# Return key of object whose value is an object that contains a property that matches a condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an object

```
const CABLE_SOURCES = {
    foxnews: {
        id: "FOXNEWSW",
        name: "Fox News",
    },
    cnn: {
        id: "CNNW",
        name: "CNN",
    },
    msnbc: {
        id: "MSNBCW",
        name: "MSNBC",
    },
    abc7: {
        id: "KGO",
        name: "ABC 7 news",
    },
};
```

My current solution looks something like

```
function getKeyName(cableSourceId) {
    let source = null;
    for (let s in CABLE_SOURCES) {
        if (CABLE_SOURCES[s].id === cableSourceId) {
            source = s;
        }
        break;
    }
    return source;
}

getKeyName("FOXNEWSW")
// foxnews
```

Is there a more functional / elegant way to rewrite `getKeyName`, either with ES6, or lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash has a [`_.findKey()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findKey) method that accepts a predicate (object in this case), and returns the 1st key with a value that matches the predicate:

```js
function getKeyName(id) {
  return _.findKey(CABLE_SOURCES, { id });
}

const CABLE_SOURCES = {"foxnews":{"id":"FOXNEWSW","name":"Fox News"},"cnn":{"id":"CNNW","name":"CNN"},"msnbc":{"id":"MSNBCW","name":"MSNBC"},"abc7":{"id":"KGO","name":"ABC 7 news"}};

console.log(getKeyName("FOXNEWSW"));
console.log(getKeyName("foo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `.find` one of the object's entries whose value has that `id`. If such an entry is found, return the first item in it (the key), otherwise return `null`:

```js
const CABLE_SOURCES = {
    foxnews: {
        id: "FOXNEWSW",
        name: "Fox News",
    },
    cnn: {
        id: "CNNW",
        name: "CNN",
    },
    msnbc: {
        id: "MSNBCW",
        name: "MSNBC",
    },
    abc7: {
        id: "KGO",
        name: "ABC 7 news",
    },
};

function getKeyName(cableSourceId) {
    const foundEntry = Object.entries(CABLE_SOURCES).find(([, { id }]) => id === cableSourceId);
    return foundEntry ? foundEntry[0] : null;
}

console.log(getKeyName("FOXNEWSW"));
console.log(getKeyName("foo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) combination. Once you have the found object, just need to access `name` property.

`Object.keys()` documentation states:

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

`Array.prototype.find()` documentation states:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Like the following:

```js
const CABLE_SOURCES = {
    foxnews: {
        id: "FOXNEWSW",
        name: "Fox News",
    },
    cnn: {
        id: "CNNW",
        name: "CNN",
    },
    msnbc: {
        id: "MSNBCW",
        name: "MSNBC",
    },
    abc7: {
        id: "KGO",
        name: "ABC 7 news",
    },
};

const getKeyName = text => CABLE_SOURCES[Object.keys(CABLE_SOURCES).find(i => CABLE_SOURCES[i].id === text)].name;

const result = getKeyName("FOXNEWSW");

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!